# MVC, проблема с выводом html

Tags: php, mvc

Создал простое приложение mvc, в представлении (вьюхе) есть главный шаблон примерно такой:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>title</title>
    <meta name="discription" content="desc">
</head>
<body>
    <?php echo $content; ?>
</body>
</html>
```

этот шаблон вызывается из контроллера так: `$this->render('index',['content'=>'test']);`
и проблема в том, что если выводить любые переменные ещё до вызова представления,  то после вызова метода `$this->render('index',['content'=>'test']);`, содержимое шаблона попадает в тег `<body>` вместе с переменными, т.е. всё содержимое шаблона, вызванного с помощью `render`, вместе с `<head>` находится внутри `<body>`.
Как этого можно избежать, чтобы к примеру если с помощью var_dump выводить переменные допустим в любом месте до вызова `render`, то чтобы эти переменные не ломали шаблон?
т.е. чтобы теги `<head>` небыли в `<body>`.
Как это правильно сделать?

Comment: Не делать var_dump где попало.

Comment: @ArchDemon, так в любых фреймворках можно выводить переменные в любом месте. Как там это сделано?

Comment: @ArchDemon, правильно ли будет такое решение, что в точке входа, в файле `index.php` включить буфер `ob_start()`, а перед вызовом `render` очищать буфер и выводить его в шаблоне?

Comment: Правильно. Вы никак, кроме задействования буфера вывода, не сделаете свою хотелку. В некоторых случаях это единственная возможность обеспечить работоспособность при некоторых ситуациях